# "Establishing secure connection", but website is not accessible

Tags: connection, windows-8.1, antivirus

I was doing some testing on my laptop using IISCrypto utility to disable TLS 1.0 and many Ciphers. After that I noticed that most of websites became unavailable. I am always using Google Chrome. Thereit is showing "Establishing secure connection" in the left bottom corner but the website is unavailable. Not all websites, I can access Youtube.com for example. It seems that it is blocking all https websites. But not sure about that.

I also tried with IE but having exactly the same problem.

Please note that after my testing I reverted my changes back to defaults. Butseems that something is still blocking my internet connections.

I also tried to restore the Server Defaults template and restart my laptop. But it did not help either.

As the last resort I also tried to reinstall Chrome. But after I uninstalled it I could not install it again due to the same connection issue. It tries to download some files from internet during installtion.

I also scaned my laptop for viruses (boot scan). There was nothing found. Then I tried to update my Windows but also could not due to the same connection issue.

I am linking this issue with IISCrypto becase I did not do anything else serious that day.

Maybe it is worth to mention that I also tried with Tor browser and it worked. But Tor is slower that Chrome and meant for different purpose. And many other apps do not work with internet now.

I am using Windows 8.1.

I am stuck now. If anybody has any idea what else I can check it would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Alex

---

Update. Recently after installation Windows updates the problem reappeared again in exactly the same manner. I was trying out some advices from internet and suddenly found out that the problem was in Avast antivirus. Even though the avast application was not running (only Avast service was running) it was blocking my internet browsing somehow. I confirmed that by disabling all Avast shields. So internet browsing worked only when I start Avast application and disable all shields. 
After some more research I found the thread that helped me to reinstall my Avast properly. After that my internet browsing seems to be fine again so far.
This is the thread:
https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=211064.0
And this is the solution:
1. Download Avast Free Antivirus: https://files.avast.com/iavs9x/avast_free_antivirus_setup_offline.exe
2. Follow instructions: https://www.avast.com/uninstall-utility (Run this tool for all prior installed Avast versions..!!)
3. Reinstall Avast with the downloaded installer from point 1.
4. Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update how I finally solve this issue. I restore my Windows settings to a restore point. Luckily Windows 8.1 automatically does restore points regularly (every week or so). So I picked up the point before that day when I think I screwed up my system.
Now everything works fine same before.